# File System dataSource

Tags: .net, winforms, filesystems

I would like to use a custom TreeView control that use a datasource to create the tree structure. I would like to create a kind of folder browser. Instead of recreate a datasource with folders name, path, icon, ecc I was looking for an object that can do this for me!
So is there a simple way to get a dataSource representing the File System?

Thank you.

Comment: For what UI technology? Winforms? WPF? other?

Comment: Winforms! I'm sorry I did not write!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take a look here, thats an example project:

its a little bit more complicated than just adding a data source

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301943/TreeView-Explorer-using-VB-NET-2008

Comment: Thank you very much for the replay. I will look to the code you linked for some ideas, but I've already implemented a folder browser in a similar manner. The problem is that in the way I implemented the folder browser, I use custom icons instead of system icons, because I would prefer to don't use shell32 lib or similar. I've also some performance doubts. But the resource you linked doesn't help me in the way I was looking for!

Comment: I solved in a different way. But you are the only one that answered my question, so I'll accept your answer!